# Math Operation Showing as String

Tags: javascript

Having trouble with math operator not working.

```
var posfx = (dwidth - outwd) / 2 + (outwd - twd) + pdir + 1.5 * 14
                 //  =        58                    -         21
```

The pdir is an operator ( either + or - ) It's negative in this instance.   & I tried using "+ pdir +"

It's giving me a string of: "58-21", instead of a number (37). How do I get it to calculate a number?

Comment: You can use `.eval()` to solve this.

Comment: You can't use arbitrary strings in place of language operators. You can use an `if` statement to decide what to do based on the value of the string.

Comment: How do you fetch the variables?

Comment: Sounds like `pdir` is a string. Or that it gets automatically converted to one during concatenation. Can you not use `1` or `-1` and multiply instead?

Comment: @tymeJV, can you post your comment as an answer so I can downvote it?

Comment: @tymeJV some people just want to watch the world burn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheap way would be to put `eval()` around it, but you can do better than that.

Try replacing `pdir +` with `(pdir == "-" ? -1 : 1) *`

This will multiply the following term by `-1` if the operation is a subtraction.

Comment: Thanks Kolink, I think this is the most complete answer w/ good explanation, will accept in a few minutes

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the second half of the equation by -1 if it needs to be subtracting.

Answer (score 3):

If `pdir` is a string, adding it to the numbers will form  a string:

```
> 2 + '-' + 3
'2-3'
```

You could multiply by `1` or `-1` instead, depending on the value of `pdir`:

```
... + (pdir == '+' ? 1 : -1) * 1.5 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

var posfx = (dwidth - outwd) / 2 + (outwd - twd) + (pdir == '-' ? -1 : 1) * 1.5 * 14